# Color bar chart according to value in jqplot

Tags: colors, jqplot, bar-chart

I have series of 1 and 0.
I want to draw a bar chart and color the 1's in green and the 0's in red.
How do i color a bar by its value?
Thanks
Ofer

Answer (score 0):

Can't be done with stock jqPlot, but you can render out two series, one for 1's and one for 0's, each with different color.  (I'm assuming a line/bar chart here, right?)  Then just hide the legend and you're good to go.